# Creating a Docker Compose for my Blazor WASM / nginx docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've got the following problem.

I created a **Blazor WASM** application (a simple tapcounter)
I added **Docker Support** and followed this tutorial [Containerising a BLazor Webassembly](https://chrissainty.com/containerising-blazor-applications-with-docker-containerising-a-blazor-webassembly-app/)

So this is my **dockerfile**:

[image: Dockerfile]

So when i **build and run** my dockerfile using those commands everything works just fine.

```
docker build -t tapcounter .
docker run -p 8070:80 tapcounter
```

Then I **pushed** my docker image to docker hub to make it available for everybody.

```
docker push darkatek7/tapcounter:latest
```

Now I created a **docker-compose.yml**

```
---
version: '3.4'
services:
  tapcounter:
    container_name: tapcounter
    image: darkatek7/tapcounter               # docker image
    ports:
      - 8070:80                               # port used for localhost ip
    restart: unless-stopped                   # restart policy
```

But when I run my file I get following **error**:

```
Attaching to tapcounter
tapcounter    | The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
tapcounter    |   * You intended to execute a .NET application:
tapcounter    |       The application 'TapCounter.Web.dll' does not exist.
tapcounter    |   * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
tapcounter    |       No .NET SDKs were found.
tapcounter    | 
tapcounter    | Download a .NET SDK:
tapcounter    | https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
tapcounter    | 
tapcounter    | Learn about SDK resolution:
tapcounter    | https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
```

I guess it's because a nginx container is missing, but I couldn't get anything to work.

There's my code: [TapCounter on Github](https://github.com/Darkatek7/TapCounter)

There's my Docker Hub page: [TacpCounter Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/darkatek7/tapcounter)

Help would be appreciated!